# Flexbox positioning text inside image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, css-position, react-native-flexbox

I'm using React Native and trying to create a specific layout.

I have an image, vertically & horizontally centred (within a View) and some Text on top of the image also vertically & horizontally centred. The Text needs to come on top of image/background image therefore I put it inside the image tag.

Now the content of that text can be very long and because it is inside the image tag, it wraps.

How can I make it so the content inside Text won't wrap and still be on top of the Image?

**My layout so far:**

[image]

**The layout I'm trying to achieve**

[image]

**My code:**

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
  <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
    <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
      <View style={styles.categoryIndexContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.categoryIndex}>01</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.middleContainer}>
      <Image source={img} style={styles.categoryImage}>
        <Text style={styles.categoryName}>Some very long title name</Text>
      </Image>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.rightContainer}></View>
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  categoryContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  leftContainer: {
    width: 50,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  middleContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    width: 50,
  },
  categoryName: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
  },
  categoryImage: {
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
  },
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify on `categoryName` style: `position: 'absolute'` then set the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` attributes until you place the `Text` above the `Image`.

Comment: Hi, I did try position absolute on categoryName but the content is still wrapping.

Comment: you should remove the Text component inside the Image component. They should be two separate components

Comment: Right — removing the Text from inside the Image & adding position absolute keeps the Text from wrapping but for some reason the Image appears above the Text (even though the Text component comes before the Image component).

Comment: the Text should come after the Image

Comment: You are right, my bad. It works. Thanks a lot for your help.